# GET Access token from API (oauth2)

Tags: php, python, oauth-2.0

I am very beginner at Python scripting and i have a problem.

I am trying to rewrite PHP code to Python to get Access token from API for further use.

```
##/* Request for access token */

$base_url = "myurl";
$client_id="1234";
$client_secret="5678";

$client_details = "${client_id}:${client_secret}";

$context = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
    'method' => 'POST',
    'header' => "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n" .
                "Authorization : Basic $client_details\r\n",
    'content' => "grant_type=client_credentials"
    )
));

$response = file_get_contents($base_url.'/apis/oauth2/Token.php', false, $context);
$res =  json_decode($response);
$token = $res->access_token;
```

This is what i am trying to do in Python.

My Python code is:

```
import urllib
import sys
import json
import requests

base_url = 'myurl'
client_id='1234'
client_secret='5678'

response = requests.post(base_url+'/apis/oauth2/Token.php',
                    auth=(client_id, client_secret))

print(response.json())
```

but this is not working

Python is returning:

```
{'error': 'invalid_request', 'error_description': 'The grant type was not specified in the request'}
```

I know that i am missing everything from the context variable from PHP Code. Do you know if there is a python method to create context like stream_context_create in PHP or maybe could you give me some tips how can i do it?

Comment: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#json-response-content - the `json` member is a method, not a value. Try adding parenthesis: `print(response.json())`

Comment: Thanks i am a bit closer to have my token :)

Comment: Your python code seems to be doing a rather different request from the php, so hardly surprising it doesn't work, assuming you are running the python against the exact same service as the php. The php does a POST, your Python does a GET. The php fills in some headers and provides content, the python doesn't appear to do either, you are putting auth in the query string. Have you tried making the python version do *exactly* the same POST as the php? Not sure what you mean by context, but requests does have a session which will persist e.g. cookies across multiple get/post.

Comment: you are right i changed get to post. What i mean byt context? i mean $context = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
    'method' => 'POST',
    'header' => "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n" .
                "Authorization : Basic $client_details\r\n",
    'content' => "grant_type=client_credentials"
    )
));

Comment: this is a better fit for what you're trying to achieve, will make it a breeze https://github.com/requests/requests-oauthlib

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem.
This is the code:

```
import urllib
import sys
import json
import requests

base_url = 'https://myurl.com'
client_id='1234'
client_secret='5678'
grant_type='client_credentials'

response = requests.post(base_url+'/apis/oauth2/Token.php',
                        auth=(client_id, client_secret),
                         data={'grant_type':grant_type,'client_id':client_id,'client_secret':client_secret})
print(response.json())
```